# CI using Gitlab and Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci

I'm using [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) for developing my web application, and `Gitlab` as my remote git repository.
I want to configure a continuous deployment such that on every push to the master, the `npm run deploy` script will be executed.

From my local pc, executing `npm run deploy` builds the node application and push it to the remote `heroku` git repository. It uses the local credentials on my pc.

I have configured the gitlab runner (in the `.yml` file) to execute the same `npm run deploy`, but it fails with `Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': No such device or address`.
I need to find a way to authenticate the gitlab runner to heroku. I have tried to set env variable `HEROKU_API_KEY`, but it also didn't work.

How can I push from my gitlab runner to my heroku git repo?

Comment: Can we see your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Also see this, it's Python but it might be helpful: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.html#configure-project

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dlp` in your yml. Try something like this in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
    - apt-get -qq update
    - npm set progress=false
    - npm install --silent

deploy:
    script:
    - npm run deploy
    - apt-get install -yqq ruby ruby-dev --silent
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=your-app-name --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
    - master
```

You preferaby want to add the env variable $HEROKU_API_KEY from GitLab, not here directly.

Comment: Its also worth mentioning here that you can use multiple images at different stages of the build. you can add `image: ruby:latest` to the deploy step and `image: node:latest` this allows you to switch around with docker using `artifacts: ` to pass built files between stages.